# Not able to login to DocuSign API from MVC application

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to connect with DocuSign using DocuSign API in my C# MVC application:

```
// initialize client for desired environment (for production change to www)
ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

// configure 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' header
string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + credentials.Username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + credentials.Password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + credentials.IntegratorKey + "\"}";

if (!Configuration.Default.DefaultHeader.ContainsKey("X-DocuSign-Authentication"))
{
Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
}

// login call is available in the authentication api 
AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
```

> On authApi.Login() I am getting below error:
>
> Error calling Login:  Message.TemplateName: authenticationrequired
>
> Message.Language: Fallback
>
> McAfee Web Gateway - Notification - Authentication Required

I think this error might be due to my proxy in my company system.
Can anyone please let me know if they are familiar with this error.

Thanks advance for the response!!

Comment: Did you try to execute the same code out of your company system ? 
Did you make sure that the credentials in the header string match the actual ones ?

Comment: No i haven't tried using this code outside company. I have verified the credentials. 
I am able to see my calls logged in DocuSign logs(under Request logging : https://appdemo.docusign.com/preferences/security)

Comment: I'd recommend to try out of your company's network. When you look at the logs, do you see your envelopes in "Created_CreateAndSendEnvelope.txt" ?

Comment: Also, did you try to create a DocuSign envelope via Postman to see if by any chance you would get a different result ?

Comment: Thanks @Frederic I tried the same code from my home network and it's working fine. I am able to get the response back. So now it's confirmed either my company proxy Or firewall is blocking me to access DocuSign. Can you please tell now what can be done in this scenario?

Comment: Ok, good to know. At this point, I would recommend that you contact your company's IT and ask them to whitelist the DocuSign URL/IP so that your requests can get through the proxy/firewall.
I had to do the same procedure for another vendor we were integrating with and that definitely helped.

Comment: now i am think we are on track. For development purpose i am using "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi". So if i whitelist this URL it will work? And do i need to be concerned about any ports?

Comment: I was in touch with my network team they want URL endpoint/points, can you please help me with this? URL is : "demo.docusign.net/restapi"

Comment: Correct, the URL that you list is the one for the DocuSign demo servers. As for the production server, it will depend on your account, DocuSign assigns a production URL that can be different from an account to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the resolution,
As network team was not ready to include URL in their white list.(not sure why??)

```
public DocuSignClient(Credentials credentials)
{
      // initialize client for desired environment (for production change to www)
      ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
      Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;

      // configure 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' header
      string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + credentials.Username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + credentials.Password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + credentials.IntegratorKey + "\"}";

      if (!Configuration.Default.DefaultHeader.ContainsKey("X-DocuSign-Authentication"))
      {
          Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
      }

      WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.corp.ups.com:8080", true)
      {
          UseDefaultCredentials = false,
          Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ABC", "XYZ")
      };

      apiClient.RestClient.Proxy = webProxy;

      // login call is available in the authentication api 
      AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
      LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

      // parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to multiple accounts)
      this.AccountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;

 }
```

Please make sure to follow the sequence for WebProxy.